# Unable to clear text in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm developing a program that will read a text file and convert it into json format. When user clicked on "change data" it will deleted the previous data and change to new data. But the problem is whenever I clicked on "change data", the data will write into it without overwrite the previous keys. I tried with reviewjson.delete("1.0", END) but it seem like not working. My goal is to delete every previous keys and view current keys only.

**Image**

[image]

**Sample Code**

```
from tkinter import *
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


root = Tk()
root.title("Foghorn Publisher")
width = 1000
height = 680
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
root.minsize(1000, 900)
root.maxsize(1000, 900)


root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))


file_data = OrderedDict()

global reviewjson
reviewjson = Text(root, bg='black', foreground="white")
reviewjson.place(x=1,y=1)
reviewjson.config(state=NORMAL)

List = ["abc","haha","fafafasf", "afasfasfasfa","asfasfasf"]
try:
    for content in List:
        file_data["data1"] = content[0:10]

        # output to JSON
        global tmp

        tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t") + "\n" + "\n"

        reviewjson.insert(END, tmp)

except:
    raise


def changedata():

        reviewjson.delete(1.0, "end")
        try:
            for content in List:
                file_data["data2"] = content[5:20]

                # output to JSON
                global tmp

                tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t") + "\n" + "\n"

                reviewjson.insert("end", tmp)

        except:
            raise

ChangeDataBtn = Button(root, text="change data", command=changedata, width=11)
ChangeDataBtn.place(x=300, y=400)

# ========================================Open Window==================================



# ========================================INITIALIZATION===================================
if __name__ == '__main__':

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need to clear the dictionary so add `file_data.clear()` in `changedata` function

Comment: Also use `"1.0"` instead of `1.0`. It might save you headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't directing at `file_data.delete()` or  `file_data.clear()`.

They are work without error, but **file_data**'s value was given before:

`file_data["data1"] = content[0:10]`
We need to clear it out.

So, you only need to change your `changedata()` function:

```
def changedata():   
    reviewjson.delete(1.0, "end")   
    file_data.clear()
    
    try:
        for content in List:
            file_data["data2"] = content[5:20]
            # output to JSON
            tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t") + "\n" + "\n"
            reviewjson.insert(1.0, tmp)
    except:
        raise
```